# C# .net MVC Http client.GetAsync(ListOfUrls)

Tags: c#, .net

Is there a way to get the response from a list of URLS instead of one urls and pass it to the view?

Controller:

```
string[] baseUrl = {"url1","url2"}

using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())

                foreach(var url in baseUrl)
                {
                    using (HttpResponseMessage res = await client.GetAsync(url))

                    using (HttpContent content = res.Content)
                    {
                        var value = res.Headers.GetValues("CUSTOM_HEADER").FirstOrDefault();
                        repsonseViewModel.customHeaderValue = value.ToString(); //to get the Header value in model

                        string data = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                        repsonseViewModel.Data = data;
                    }
```

What it does so far: it takes the response and the customHeader value. But I don't know how to make it take the same for all URLs in the list.

VIEW:

```
@foreach (var urlItem in Model.customHeaderValue)
{
    if (Model.customHeaderValue != null)
    {
        <textarea rows="5" cols="100">@Model.customHeaderValue</textarea>
    }
}


@foreach (var urlItem in Model.Data)
{
    <br />
    @if (Model.Data != null)
    {
        <textarea rows="20" cols="100">@Model.Data</textarea>
    }
}
```

Comment: I suspect the actual problem is that you're modifying the same `responseViewModel` instead of returning a separate instance for each URL. This isn't an `HttpClient` issue.

Comment: save your responses in some collection and then manage that collection. As @PanagiotisKanavos said, you are operating in the end only with latest response

Comment: Besides, if `Data` is a string, `foreach (var urlItem in Model.Data)` will return individual characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this model:

```
class ViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<string> CustomHeaderValues { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> Data { get; set; }
}
```

You could do this:

```
var headers = new string[baseUrl.Length];
var data = new string[baseUrl.Length];

await Task.WhenAll(baseUrl.Select(async (url, i) =>
{
    using (HttpResponseMessage res = await client.GetAsync(url))
    using (HttpContent content = res.Content)
    {
        var value = res.Headers.GetValues("CUSTOM_HEADER").FirstOrDefault();
        headers[i] = value.ToString();

        data[i] = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
}));

return new ViewModel
{
    CustomHeaderValues = headers,
    Data = data
};
```

Using `Enumerable.Select` has the added benefit that subsequent HTTP requests can be initiated before writing for the previous to complete, unlike with the `foreach` approach which serialises the requests.

View:

```
@foreach (var urlItem in Model.CustomHeaderValues)
{
    <textarea rows="5" cols="100">@urlItem</textarea>
}


@foreach (var urlItem in Model.Data)
{
    <br />
    <textarea rows="20" cols="100">@urlItem</textarea>
}
```

---

As an aside, if you're using .Net Core 2.1+, you should be using [IHttpClientFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests) instead of manually creating `HttpClient` instances.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That worked like charm.

As I need to use it different I've modified the return into my model:

```
MyMode result =  new MyModel
            {
                CustomHeaderValuesList = headers,
                URLData = data
            };

return View("myView", result);
```